# How can I limit input current to a raspberry Pi to 2 amps from a high current battery?

Tags: current, resistors, raspberry-pi, current-limiting, constant-current

The circuit I currently have consists of a motor circuit and a raspberry pi circuit connected to the same battery. (2 series circuits from the same battery).
The problem is that during idle motor, a very small current flows through the circuit and when the motor is running, it could draw up to 30 amps of current. If this happens, how can I always maintain a constant 2 amps current as input to the Raspberry Pi? The make and model of the current limiting resistor would help.

[image]

Comment: ‘2 series circuits from the same battery’ isn’t clear. Draw a diagram.

Comment: Added a diagram @Chu

Comment: You don't have "2 series circuits from the same battery", you have 2 *parallel* circuits from the same battery. The current through each one is independent from the current in the other.

Comment: understood. Thanks.

Comment: You _never_ want a current limiting resistor to an active load like a RPi. The RPi will consume what it needs. If its power is limited, it will fail in unpredictable ways.

Comment: Understood. Thanks :) and folks I apologise for the wrong schematic.. The input is a standard RPi input..

Comment: Also, the 2A requirement for the RPi means that its power supply needs to be able to provide 2A _just in case_ the RPi needs it. The RPi may need to draw that much current occasionally, but it won't always need that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi will draw whatever current it requires, regardless of the current drawn by the motor (assuming the battery can supply all the current required by both the Pi and motor).

Comment: I have added a diagram, does it still apply Peter?

Comment: Why are you connecting the SPI pin to the positive side of the battery, and GPIO5 to the negative?  I would ecpect the Pi's Ground pin to connect to the battery negative.  Doesn't the Pi require a 5 Volt power supply?  Where is that?

Comment: No the connections are for simplicity sake. It's not connected to GPIO.

Comment: When we ask you to show a schematic, we expect you to show a CORRECT schematic, showing you you really have (or intend to have) things connected.  All we know about your circuit is what you show us.  You WILL need a DC-DC converter to reduce the battery voltage to 5 volts for the Pi.

Comment: Understood and I appologise for showing the wrong schematic.